# Bind NavigationView menu

Tags: android, data-binding, menu, android-databinding, android-navigationview

Is there any way now to bind `NavigationView` menu (using DataBinding)? I'm interested in binding some `ActionView`s. Now I'm using `binding.nvview.post(..);` and in post`DataBindingUtil.bind(findViewById(my_view_id))`, but sometimes `post` happens before menu inflated, so DataBinding doesn't work. In fact I don't even need to set variable, because layout takes value from `Singleton`.

So, there is two questions:

- Can I bind NavigationView menu?
- Can I create some custom view, that will bind itself when inflating and then set it to MenuItem ActionView?